# Preview Rendering Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to code a round button but Android Studio is unfortunately previewing improperly. Have any of you had this happen or know how to fix it? I don't understand how the rendering could fail. Here's the screen:
[Preview tab rendering error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utPYl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **rebuild** or **clean** project. You can also **restart android studio**. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering error went away after restarting android studio.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @Eli I cannot pin point what went wrong. Restarting the studio fixed the problem.